Explicity defined iid random variables
I ran into a probability exercise in class the other day:
Let $\left\{X_{n}\right\}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of random variables such that
$\forall\ n, m \in \mathbb{N}$:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[X_{n}X_{m}\right] =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if}\ n = m
\\
0, & \text{if}\ n \neq m
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
"Give an example of this sequence."

I know that this is an iid sequence, but how can we explicitly define these random variables ?
$$
\mbox{Assume let's say}\quad \left(\left[0,1\right), \mathcal{B}\left(\mathbb{[0, 1)},
   \mathbb{P}\right)\right).
$$
I played around with
$$
X_n(\omega) = 2 \times \mathbf{1}_{\omega\ \in\ \left[0, 1/2\right)}\!\!\left(\omega\right)\ -\ 1
$$
but I ran into the same issue with randomness seen below.
How can we formally construct this iid sequence ?.
Does it make sense to have $\omega_{n}$'s for example which identify these variables ?.

I saw this post but I am still struggling to draw connections to this context.

Why not just take all of them independently equal to the variable which is $\pm 1$ with equal probability?

How do formalize that "equal probability" explicitly though without becoming deterministic?

What do you mean?  This is the standard Bernoulli variable.  Well, I am taking values ${\pm 1}$ instead of ${0,1}$, but that's hardly a big change.

I guess I'm confused by the fact that we're defining a $X_n(\omega)$ without any explicit reliance on either $n$ or $\omega$. In the sense that in the other post the functions $X_1, X_2$ are explicity defined in exhaustive terms with $X_1(\omega_1) = x$ etc, rather than with some sort of constructive definition.

I.e, even for two variables, let's say $X_1, X_2$, to get the properties above I would define: $X_1(\omega_1) = -1, X_1(\omega_2) = -1, X_1(\omega_3)=1, X_1(\omega_4)=1, X_2(\omega_1) = -1, X_2(\omega_2) = 1, X_2(\omega_3) = -1, X_2(\omega_4) = 1$. This is kindof what I was getting at with the $\omega_n$, is there a way to generate some kind of explicit function $X_n(\omega_i)$ which accomplishes this over $[0,1)$?

I don't understand. Surely it's enough to just say that you have iid variables with the given fixed form.  If you want,  choose a real number uniformly on $[0,1]$ and let $X_i$ be the $i^{th}$ digit (replacing $0$ with $-1$. ) Fix a form for terminating strings if you want,  but it's probability $0$ so it doesn't matter.

Taking $X_n$ to be a standard normal random variable with mean $0$ and variance $1$ also works.

How can they be iid if there is an explicit reliance on $n$????

@Paul An explicit reliance on $n$ doesn't prevent the i.i.d. property. If $U\sim\text{Uniform}[0,1]$, and $Y_n$ is the $n$th bit of the binary expansion of $U$, then indeed $Y_n$, $n\geq 1$ are i.i.d., taking values $0$ and $1$ with probability $1/2$ each.

An explicit example would be to take your measure space as $[0,1]^{\Bbb{N}}$ with the product measure and product sigma algebra and let $X_{i}(\omega)=2\pi_{i}(\omega)-1$. Where $\pi_{i}$'s are the projection maps to the $i$-th coordinate.
